# Algebraic tensor product of C*-algebras extends via ideals? Application to restriction theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, tensor-products

Is the following assertion and the proof below correct,
or am I missing something very important?

Moreover, would the corollaries be correct then?

Besides, I would also appreciate a lot any comment, advice, suggestion about the mathematical writing like structure, titles, phrasing, layout, arguments, etc. :)

## Problem

> **Assertion:** Given C*-algebras $A$ and $D$ and let $I\trianglelefteq A$ be a closed two-sided ideal in $A$.
>   Consider their algebraic tensor products $A\odot D$ and $I\odot D$, respectively.
>   
>   
>   Let $B(H)$ denote the bounded operators over a Hilbert space $H$.
>   
>   
>   Then every *-morphism $\varphi:I\odot D\to B(H)$ extends to
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> A\odot D & \xrightarrow{\Phi} & B(H) \\
> \uparrow & \nearrow\varphi & \\
> I\odot D
> \end{matrix}$$
>   for a unique *-morphism $\Phi:A\odot D\to B(H)$.

## Application/Motivation

As an interesting application of the assertion we would obtain the following

> **Corollary:** Given C*-algebras $A$ and $B$.
>   Denote their multiplier algebras by $\mathcal{M}A$ and $\mathcal{M}B$, respectively.
>   
>   Consider their algebraic tensor products $A\odot B$ and $\mathcal{M}A\odot\mathcal{M}B$.
>   
>   
>   Let $B(H)$ denote the bounded operators over a Hilbert space $H$.
>   
>   
>   Then every *-morphism $\varphi:A\odot B\to B(H)$ extends to
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> \mathcal{M}A\odot \mathcal{M}B & \xrightarrow{\Phi} & B(H) \\
> \uparrow & \nearrow\varphi & \\
> A\odot B
> \end{matrix}$$
>   for a unique *-morphism $\Phi:A\odot D\to B(H)$.

as well as a nice proof for the restriction theorem:

> **Corollary:** Given C*-algebras $A$ and $B$.
>   Consider their algebraic tensor product $A\odot B$.
>   
>   
>   Let $B(H)$ denote the bounded operators over a Hilbert space $H$.
>   
>   
>   Then every *-morphism $\varphi:A\odot B\to B(H)$ restricts to
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> A\odot B & \xrightarrow{\varphi} & B(H) \\
> \uparrow & \nearrow\varphi_A\cdot\varphi_B & \\
> A\times B
> \end{matrix}$$
>   for unique *-morphisms $\varphi_A:A\to B(H)$ and $\varphi_B:B\to B(H)$.
>   
>   
>   Moreover, $\varphi_A$ and $\varphi_B$ commute.

## Proof

*Proof:* a) Existence:

Though the idea of the construction is pretty simple, the proof can get pretty lengthy in detail.
Thus let us split the proof into several parts:

i.) Reduction to non-degenerate *-morphism:

Denote the kernel of the image by
$$\mathcal{N}(I\odot D):=\{v\in H:\varphi(I\odot D)v=0\}=\bigcap_{y\in I\odot D}\mathcal{N}y$$
while the range of the image by
$$\mathcal{R}(I\odot D):=\varphi(I\odot D)H=\bigcup_{y\in I\odot D}\mathcal{R}y$$
and denote its closed linear span by $H_\varphi:=\overline{\operatorname{span}}\mathcal{R}(I\odot D)$.

Then we obtain the orthogonal decomposition
$$H=H_\varphi\oplus H_\varphi^\bot=\overline{\operatorname{span}}\mathcal{R}(I\odot D)\oplus\mathcal{N}(I\odot D)$$
and whence the matrix representation
$$\varphi=\begin{pmatrix}\pi&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\pi:I\odot D\to B(H_\varphi)$ is a non-degenerate *-morphism.

For shorthand notation redefine $H:=H_\varphi$.

Thus the problem reduces to extending a non-degenerate *-morphism $\pi:I\odot D\to B(H)$.

ii.) Construction:

Fix an element $d_0\in D$ and define the map $\Pi(\_\odot d_0):A\to B(H)$ by
$$\Pi(a\odot d_0)\pi(i\odot d)v:=\pi(ai\odot d_0d)v$$
for $a\in A$, $i\in I$, $d\in D$ and $v\in H$ and extend linearly.

iii.) Well-Definedness:

This is indeed well-defined by the following standard argument,
which is actually the heart of the proof:

As a first instance, note that for $d_0\geq0$ the linear map
$$\pi(\_\odot d_0):I\to B(H):i\mapsto\pi(i\odot d_0)$$
is positive between C*-algebras and as such bounded.

But a C*-algebra is spanned by its positive elements,
and thus $\pi(\_\odot d_0)$ is bounded also for $d_0\in D$ not necessarily positive.

With this observation in hand we obtain that
$$\pi(eai\odot d_0)\xrightarrow{e\to1}\pi(ai\odot d_0)$$
for $a\in  A$, $i\in I$ and any approximate unit $e\in I$ for $I$.

Let now $a\in A$ and $\sum_ki_k\odot d_kv_k\in\operatorname{span}\pi(I\odot D)H$.
Moreover let $e\in I$ be a, now bounded, approximate unit for $I$. Then
\begin{align*}
\|\Pi(a\odot d_0)\sum_k\pi(i_k\odot d_k)v_k\|=&\|\sum_k\pi(ai_k\odot d_0d_k)v_k\|\\
=&\|\lim_e\sum_k\pi(eai_k\odot d_0d_k)v_k\|\\
=&\lim_e\|\pi(ea\odot d_0)\sum_k\pi(i_k\odot d_k)v_k\|\\
\leq&\sup_e\|\pi(\_\odot d_0)\|\cdot\|ea\|\cdot\|\sum_k\pi(i_k\odot d_k)v_k\|\\
\leq&\|\pi(\_\odot d_0)\|\cdot\sup_e\|e\|\cdot\|a\|\cdot\|\sum_k\pi(i_k\odot d_k)v_k\|,
\end{align*}
whence the operator $\Pi(a\odot d_0)$ is well-defined and bounded on $\operatorname{span}\pi(I\odot D)H$,
and thus, since $\pi$ is non-degenerate, extends to a bounded operator on $H$.

Hence, the map $\Pi(\_\odot d_0)$ is well-defined.

iv.) *-Morphism:

We may now vary the previously fixed element $d_0\in D$ as well to obtain a bilinear map
$$\Pi:A\times D\to B(H):(a,d)\mapsto \Pi(a\odot d)$$
and so to obtain a linear map, also denoted by
$$\Pi:A\odot D\to B(H):a\odot d\mapsto\Pi(a\odot d).$$
The resulting map is easily seen to be a *-morphism:

For $a_1,a_2\in A$, $d_1,d_2\in D$ as well as $\pi(i\odot d)v\in\operatorname{span}\pi(I\odot D)H$ we have
\begin{align*}
\Pi(a_1\odot d_1)\Pi(a_2\odot d_2)\pi(i\odot d)v=&\pi(a_1a_2i\odot d_1d_2d)v\\
=&\Pi(a_1a_2\odot d_1d_2)\pi(i\odot d)v,
\end{align*}
and thus, again since $\pi$ is non-degenerate,
$$\Pi(a_1\odot d_1)\Pi(a_2\odot d_2)=\Pi(a_1a_2\odot d_1d_2).$$

Involutivity follows a similar vein.

b) Uniqueness: Here, I'm not sure about the degenerate case!

Answer (score 5):

There is no uniqeness in general and I think that existence is a standard fact. Indeed, since $\varphi$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism, it extends to a $\ast$-homomorphism $\widetilde{\varphi}: I\otimes_{\mathrm{max}} D \to B(H)$. Now $I\otimes_{\mathrm{max}} D$ is an ideal in $A\otimes_{\mathrm{max}} D$, and representations always extend from ideals (using approximate identity). Therefore we get a $\ast$-homomorphism $\widetilde{\Phi}: A \otimes_{\mathrm{max}} D \to B(H)$ which restricts to $\Phi: A \odot D \to B(H)$.

As for uniqueness, it is correct to say that degenerate case is the problem. We will just consider $D=\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $A = B\oplus C$ is a direct sum of $C^{\ast}$-algebras and let $\varphi: B \to B(H)$ be a representation and then view it as a representation on $H\oplus K$, where $K$ is some Hilbert space. Then any representation $\sigma: C\to B(K)$ would provide an extension of $\varphi$ of the form $\varphi\oplus\sigma$ and this can be highly non-unique.